# How to show only the child page of the page displayed and make it dynamic on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, parent-child

It may sound silly, but apparently i am not able to show the only the child page of the page displayed on the sidebar.

My structure is

```
PAGE 1
-PAGE 1A
-PAGE 1B
-PAGE 1C
PAGE 2
-PAGE 2A
-PAGE 2B
-PAGE 2C
```

What i want is: when the user is on PAGE 1

```
-PAGE 1A
-PAGE 1B
-PAGE 1C
```

I tried all the plugins and all the code available on line (all the code I found ion this website as well about child page), but what i get is:

```
PAGE 1
-PAGE 1A
-PAGE 1B
-PAGE 1C
PAGE 2
-PAGE 2A
-PAGE 2B
-PAGE 2C
```

The whole structure. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the theme itself (this is the first time I start with  theme from scratch).

I am using this code:

```
   <?php if ( is_page( 'PAGE 1' )  ) { ?>


    <ul>
      <?php
      wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=2&show_date=modified
      &date_format=$date_format"); ?>
    </ul>


    <?php } elseif ( is_page( 'PAGE 2' )   ) { ?>


    <ul>
      <?php
      wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=9&show_date=modified
      &date_format=$date_format"); ?>
    </ul>


    <?php } else { ?>

    <ul>
      <?php
      wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=7&show_date=modified
      &date_format=$date_format"); ?>
    </ul>



    <?php } ?>
```

But apparently it doesn't understand what the page is and goes with the ELSE..

Can you help? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the the way you write the page title is correct in condition, why not use the page id instead:

```
<?php if( is_page(2)  ) { ?>

<ul>
  <?php  wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=2&show_date=modified
         &date_format=$date_format"); ?>
</ul>

<?php } elseif ( is_page(9) ) { ?>

<ul>
  <?php  wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=9&show_date=modified
         &date_format=$date_format"); ?>
</ul>

<?php } else { ?>

<ul>
  <?php   wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=7&show_date=modified
          &date_format=$date_format"); ?>
</ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it doesn't work with id either. I think i did something wrong earlier in the page but i dont know what it might be. any idea?

Comment: then it d be the problem with is_page() condition. you need to figure out why this condition does not work?